# non-deterministic content model error DTD

Tags: xml, dtd, non-deterministic, dtd-parsing

Given:

```
<!ELEMENT diagnostic-tracks (hookup*, (%step;)*, ((diagnostic-track-automated, diagnostic-track-manual) | diagnostic-track-automated | diagnostic-track-manual), evaluate*, disconnect*)>
```

and

```
<!ELEMENT diagnostic-track-automated (((%step;) | diagnostic_group)*, diagnostic_group, evaluate*)>

<!ENTITY % step "((%figtab;) | step1 | step1-alt)">
<!ENTITY % figtab "figure | figure-alt | table | table-alt | lubetab">
```

I am getting non-deterministic content model errors that diagnostic-track-automated and diagnostic_group could simultaneously match two or more tokens.

I changed to:

```
<!ELEMENT diagnostic-tracks (hookup*, (%step;)*, diagnostic-track-automated?, diagnostic-track-manual?, evaluate*, disconnect*)>
```

and

```
<!ELEMENT diagnostic-track-automated (((%step;) | diagnostic_group+)*, evaluate*)>
```

which eliminated the error messages, but I don't think my changes, especially for `diagnostic-track-automated`, are correct.

I appreciate any suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Can you add the `step` parameter entity declaration so we can see what `%step;` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you came up with for `diagnostic-tracks` appears to be what you were trying to accomplish with the original non-deterministic model:

> zero or more `hookup` elements followed by
>   zero or more elements
>   from `%step;` followed by
>   zero or one
>   `diagnostic-track-automated` element followed by
>   zero or one
>   `diagnostic-track-manual` element followed by
>   zero or more
>   `disconnect` elements

However I think the fix for `diagnostic-track-automated` is not what you originally intended.

What you propose now is:

> zero or more elements from `%step;` or `diagnostic_group` followed
>   by
>   zero or more `evaluate` elements

What I think you meant was:

> zero or more elements from `%step;` followed by 
>  one or more
>   `diagnostic_group` elements followed by
>   zero or more `evaluate`
>   elements

Which would be:

```
<!ELEMENT diagnostic-track-automated ((%step;)*, diagnostic_group+, evaluate*)>
```

Here's a full/testable example...

**DTD** (so.dtd)

```
<!ENTITY % figtab "figure | figure-alt | table | table-alt | lubetab">
<!ENTITY % step "%figtab; | step1 | step1-alt">

<!ELEMENT diagnostic-tracks (hookup*, (%step;)*, diagnostic-track-automated?, diagnostic-track-manual?, evaluate*, disconnect*)>

<!ELEMENT diagnostic-track-automated ((%step;)*, diagnostic_group+, evaluate*)>

<!ELEMENT table EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT table-alt EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT diagnostic_group EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT step1-alt EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT evaluate EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT figure EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT figure-alt EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT lubetab EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT step1 EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT diagnostic-track-manual EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT disconnect EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT hookup EMPTY>
```

**XML**

```
<!DOCTYPE diagnostic-tracks SYSTEM "so.dtd">
<diagnostic-tracks>
    <diagnostic-track-automated>
        <diagnostic_group/>
    </diagnostic-track-automated>
    <diagnostic-track-manual/>
</diagnostic-tracks>
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel this eliminated the errors. However, I thought `((%step;) | diagnostic_group+)*` meant `&step;` could follow `<diagnostic_group>`

Comment: @Caroline - Yes that's true and that's what I was trying to say with "_zero or more elements from %step; or diagnostic_group followed by_". So it's basically: `(figure|figure-alt|table|table-alt|lubetab|step1|step1-alt|diagnostic_group)*` (the `+` occurrence indicator on `diagnostic_group` doesn't mean anything because it's in that zero or more "or" group). Sorry that wasn't more clear. Hopefully my comment makes sense.

Comment: you were clear, I wasn't. I meant I thought `((%step;) | diagnostic_group+)*` would allow `%step;<diagnostic_group>%step; <diagnostic_group><evaluate>` but `((%step;)*, diagnostic_group+` would not permit a `%step;` after `<diagnostic_group>`

Comment: @Caroline - Yes, what you're saying is correct. Do you need to be able to have `%step;` after `diagnostic_group`?

Comment: yes, thanks. This is actually from the MIL STD 40051C v6.3 dtd.

Comment: @Caroline - What I would do is add a `, (%step;)*` after `diagnostic_group+` like so: `<!ELEMENT diagnostic-track-automated ((%step;)*, diagnostic_group+, (%step;)*, evaluate*)>`